# How to execute queries in online dictionary from my php site

Tags: php

I have following code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$re = '/# Split sentences on whitespace between them.
    (?<=                # Begin positive lookbehind.
      [.!?]             # Either an end of sentence punct,
    | [.!?][\'"]        # or end of sentence punct and quote.
    )                   # End positive lookbehind.
    (?<!                # Begin negative lookbehind.
      Mr\.              # Skip either "Mr."
    | Mrs\.             # or "Mrs.",
    | Ms\.              # or "Ms.",
    | Jr\.              # or "Jr.",
    | Dr\.              # or "Dr.",
    | Prof\.            # or "Prof.",
    | Sr\.              # or "Sr.",
    | T\.V\.A\.         # or "T.V.A.",
                        # or... (you get the idea).
    )                   # End negative lookbehind.
    \s+                 # Split on whitespace between sentences.
    /ix';

$text = 'Koer on hea. Kass on tore.';

$sentences = preg_split($re, $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sentences); ++$i) {
    $words = explode(" ", $sentences[$i]);
    $stringlength= str_word_count($sentences[$i]);
    $randominteger=rand(0,$stringlength-1);
    echo str_replace($words[$randominteger],"TEST",$sentences[$i]);
}
?>
```

What this code does right now is choosing one random word from every sentence in variable $text and replacing it with word TEST.

Final goal is to create a application which changes a word from every sentence(from text which user inputs) and replaces it with similar word, i mean with word which has similar meaning not looks similar. Then it outputs text with mistakes and user can correct the mistakes.

Next step I want to do is to find out in which category every word belongs. In example is it word from chemistry or geology etc. For that I want to make a query about every word in estonian dictionary. Its address is http://www.eki.ee/dict/qs/. And I want to get the category of word from there. Its included in explanation of word there.

But I have no idea how to do this or is it even possible.

I would be very thankful if someone gives me some advice hot to do it or points out some good resources.

Comment: Other than this what have you tried or where have you started? This needs to be broken up into much smaller tasks with each task being tackled separately.

Comment: Thats all the code right now. I do have thought about it and I think I realize what tasks I need to accomplish in order to make my application work, but I dont know how to write necessary code in PHP. Next thing I want to do would be making a query about word, which I change, at first I dont want to recieve any output. I just would like to know, how to make a query in online dictionary from my code.

Comment: To put it short, I want to know about how to make my code interact with website. Are there any good resources available?

Comment: Start here - http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php